# Cross compiling libjson-c : Make unsuccessful in libjson-c, Linkhash.c warning

Tags: c, cross-compiling, libjson

Should I add any flags to avoid this?

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/local/ZOHOCORP/vignesh-4691/Downloads/json-c-master'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/local/ZOHOCORP/vignesh-4691/Downloads/json-c-master'
  CC       linkhash.lo
linkhash.c: In function 'lh_char_hash':
linkhash.c:480:2: error: #warning "racy random seed initializtion if used by multiple threads" [-Werror=cpp]
 #warning "racy random seed initializtion if used by multiple threads"
  ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:585: recipe for target 'linkhash.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [linkhash.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/local/ZOHOCORP/vignesh-4691/Downloads/json-c-master'
Makefile:649: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/local/ZOHOCORP/vignesh-4691/Downloads/json-c-master'
Makefile:448: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

`cc1: all warnings being treated as errors`

Sure, find where `-Werror` is set and remove that flag. Then warnings will be only warnings.

Comment: Then how do I avoid appending -Werror in the makfiles CFLAGS. Because on ./configure it generates a makefile with -Werror appended with it